# Java: cannot find symbol class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am writing a program, which gets two values from two text fields and calculates their result.

The problem is that Java Editor shows me the following errors:

```
cannot find symbol class EditText
cannot find symbol class Button
cannot find symbol class string
cannot find symbol class variable integer
cannot find symbol class integer
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    Button btnAdd;
    TextView total;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
        secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
  }

    public void btnAdd_Click(View view)
    {
        string getfirstNumber = firstNumber.getText().toString();
        string getsecondNumber = secondNumber.getText().toString();
integer totalResult = integer.parseInt(getfirstNumber) + integer.parseInt(getsecondNumber);
total.setText("Total = " + integer.toString(totalResult));

    }
}
```

Comment: String and Integer must start with uppercase char. Have you imported the other class using `Import ...`?

Comment: What are your `import`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use following imports

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
```